# How to test method with nested for loops

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am beginer in unit testing. 
I use JUnit and Mockito. This is one example method which I want to test.

```
public List<Person> getPeopleList(List<Aggregate<Person>> aggregateList) {
    List<Person> resultList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (Aggregate<Person> aggregate : aggregateList) {
        resultList.add(aggregate);

        for (Person person : aggregate) {
            resultList.add(person);
        }
    }
    return resultList; // the result is person and aggregate list
}
```

I tried to many ways, but I can't do it well. Example:

```
@Test
public void getPeopleListTest(){
    ClassUnderTest testedClass = new ClassUnderTest();

    Aggregate aggregate = mock(Aggregate.class);
    Iterator<Aggregate<Person>> aggregateIterator = mock(Iterator.class);
    when(aggregateIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
    when(aggregateIterator.next()).thenReturn(aggregate);

    List<Aggregate<Person>> aggregateList = mock(List.class);

    aggregateList.add(aggregate);

    List<Person> list = testedClass.getPeopleList(aggregateList);

    assertEquals(1, list.size());
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't mock every possible thing. I would only mock the class you want to test and assume List behaves correctly.

```
public class Main {
    interface Person {
    }

    interface Aggregate<T> extends Person, Iterable<T> {
    }

    public static List<Person> getPeopleList(List<Aggregate<Person>> aggregateList) {
        List<Person> resultList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (Aggregate<Person> aggregate : aggregateList) {
            resultList.add(aggregate);

            for (Person person : aggregate) {
                resultList.add(person);
            }
        }
        return resultList; // the result is person and aggregate list
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Aggregate<Person> aggregate = mock(Aggregate.class);
        Aggregate<Person> aggregate2 = mock(Aggregate.class);
        Person person = mock(Person.class);
        Person person2 = mock(Person.class);
        when(aggregate.iterator()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(person).iterator());
        when(aggregate2.iterator()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(person2).iterator());

        List<Person> list = getPeopleList(
                Arrays.asList(aggregate, aggregate2));
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("size: " + list.size());
    }
}
```

prints

```
[Mock for Aggregate, hashCode: 2037567902, Mock for Person, hashCode: 1629493852, Mock for Aggregate, hashCode: 44220373, Mock for Person, hashCode: 182467149]
size: 4
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you mock `Aggregate<Person>` and `Person`. In my eyes, this is not necessary.

Comment: It depends on what you are testing. If you want to test the method without assumptions about these interfaces, you need to mock them. If you are confident they behave correctly you don't need to mock anything.

Comment: Thank you for all responses. I would like to use mocks for `Aggregate<Person>` and `Person`. I think I understand the line: `when(aggregate.iterator()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(person).iterator());` When on `Aggregate` iterator is called, it returns iterator of `Person`. But how can I change the number of aggregates and people. I want to check e.g. two agregates and two people. I have no idea how to do this :|

Comment: @LancerX I have changed the example for two Aggregate and Person. BTW you can build these in a loop if you have more than 2.

Comment: I don't know if this solution is correct. When I remove lines `when(aggregate...` and `when(aggregate2...` the tests still are passed. Apart from that `getPeopleList`should returns list with four elements (aggregate, aggregate2, person, person2) not two.

Comment: That's what your code does. it adds the aggregates and the persons in it.  Perhaps it should only add the persons.

Comment: Exactly it should return 2*aggregate and 2*person -> 4*item. And the code does it. But the test in your example above, is passed when `assertEquals(2, list.size())`, and should be 4.

Comment: Can you try the updated example? It works correctly as far as I can see.

Comment: You are right. In this updated example list size is 4, and if I remove `when(aggregate...` it fails. I really do not understand why in test removing `when` causes nothing and why list size is 2. I will think about it. Of course you have point from me. Thank you!

Comment: If I comment out those lines I get a NullPointerException. I am using mockito 1.9.0.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask yourself what is it that you're trying to test? In the example function you want to check that when function is given a list of aggregates it returns a mixed flattened list of aggregates and persons.

So, I wouldn't mock List, instead check that result list does contain all the expected items:

```
Aggregate aggregate = new Aggregate(...);
//add persons to aggregate.

List<Aggregate<Person>> aggregateList = new ArrayList();
aggregateList.add(aggregate);

List<Person> list = testedClass.getPeopleList(aggregateList);
assertEquals(Collections.singletonList(aggregate), result);
```

Otherwise if you change the way you iterate over all the items in the argument List you would need to update the tests.

Another things you could test:

1. List given as an argument is not modified.
2. Function checks for `null` argument.

   ```
   Preconditions.checkNotNull(aggregateList, "AggregateList cannot be null");
   ```
3. Empty argument results in empty result.